# expected primary-expression before ‘m_Buffer’

Tags: c++

This is my first question so excuse me if it's not clear.
I am trying to run this code using my first implementation with smart pointers; But it results to an error that i'm not understanding. I needed to put (void) because if not, it shows me a message saying that it's not possible to convert from char to void*.

Error: error: expected primary-expression before ‘m_Buffer’
19 |         (void) std::unique_ptr m_Buffer(new char[m_Size]);

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <memory>

class String
{
private:
    char* m_Buffer;
    unsigned int m_Size;

public:
    String(const char* string)
    {
        m_Size = strlen(string);
        (void) std::unique_ptr<char> m_Buffer(new char[m_Size]);
        memcpy(m_Buffer, string, m_Size);
    }

    String(const String& other) // Copy constructor: takes a reference to the
        : m_Size(other.m_Size)  //same class, we can = delete
    {

        (void) std::unique_ptr<char> m_Buffer(new char[m_Size]);
        memcpy(m_Buffer, other.m_Buffer, m_Size);
        std::cout << "Copy constructor worked" << std::endl;
    }


    ~String()
    {
        //delete[] m_Buffer;
        std::cout << "Deleted vector" << std::endl;
    }

    char& operator[](unsigned int index)
    {
        return m_Buffer[index];
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const String& string);

};

void PrintString(const String& string) //IMPORTANT: const, we don't want to edit
                                       // and we can pass temporal values.
{
    std::cout << string << std::endl;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const String& string)
{
    stream << string.m_Buffer;
    return stream;
}


int main()
{
    String string = "Cherno";
    String second = string;

    second[2] = 'a';

    PrintString(string); //Near always pass our objects by reference.
    PrintString(second);
}
```

Comment: What is going on here `(void) std::unique_ptr<char> m_Buffer(new char[m_Size]);`? If you just want a `char*` drop all that stuff about the `unique_ptr` and I don't even know what you're intending `(void)` to do there.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `(void) std::unique_ptr<char> m_Buffer(new char[m_Size]);`?

Comment: Did Cherno teach you this?

Comment: Thanks you all for the answers. I'm new in c++ and I just tried to add an implementation of smart pointers to a code that I took by looking cherno's videos. But it has nothing to do with him. I put (void) because of an error displayed on me saying that memcpy have to accept a void*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(void) std::unique_ptr<char> m_Buffer(new char[m_Size]);
```

The `(void)` needs to go. You have added it because of a completely unrelated error. Now, to fix that error, you need to realize that `memcpy` accepts a `void*`, not a `char*`. The cast exists and is implicit, but you need to get the raw pointer from the smart pointer via get().

```
memcpy(m_Buffer.get(), other.m_Buffer.get(), m_Size);
```

However, you should realize that `unique_ptr` is going to call `delete` (and not `delete[]`) on your pointer which will result in undefined behavior. You need to have `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`

Comment: They should probably drop the `unique_ptr` entirely, since it shadows the member variable, which remains uninitialized after the constructor is called

Comment: A `std::vector<char>` is probably the right thing to use here.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Let's go one step further, dispose of the whole String class that is attempted to be implemented and just use std::string :)

Comment: Or, another option is to change the `char* m_Buffer` member to a `std_unique_ptr<char>` type (plus suitable modifications elsewhere).

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, you helped me and solved the code. However, I have one point that I am not fully understanding. When using smart pointers, I thought the "only" difference (at least with unique_ptr) was that they automatically deletes after getting out of scope, meaning that you don't need to do the delete. But now I am seeing that in some cases, you need to get the "raw" pointer from the smart pointer. What else do an unique pointer have? Any link to help me fully understand this stuff please? Really thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Dont bother with unique_ptr here as there is enough going on in this problem without having to resort to excessive automation. If you're implementing a library it's best to be conservative.

Here's the solution you were looking for. Also note that when you take a string size/length you need to add one to the char array to account for the null terminator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <memory>

class String
{
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> m_Buffer;
    unsigned int m_Size;

public:
    String(const char *string)
    {
        m_Size = strlen(string) + 1;
        m_Buffer.reset(new char[m_Size]);
        memcpy(m_Buffer.get(), string, m_Size);
    }

    String(const String &other) : m_Size(other.m_Size)
    {
        m_Buffer.reset(new char[m_Size]);
        memcpy(m_Buffer.get(), other.m_Buffer.get(), m_Size);
        std::cout << "Copy constructor worked" << std::endl;
    }

    ~String()
    {
        std::cout << "Deleted vector" << std::endl;
    }

    char& operator[](unsigned int index)
    {
        return m_Buffer[index];
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const String &string);

};

void PrintString(const String &string)
{
    std::cout << string << std::endl;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const String &string)
{
    stream << string.m_Buffer.get();
    return stream;
}

int main()
{
    String string = "Cherno";
    String second = string;

    second[2] = 'a';

    PrintString(string);
    PrintString(second);
}
```